# Is there any way to create a drawable shape (xml-android) border open from the top like in the picture shown below?

Tags: android, xml

I want to create a border to a set of icons and give them a title above them which it will be in the middle of that border like the picture below.

[image]

I'll be really thankful if you find a way by creating a drawable shape .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it yhis way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="15dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Label 1: Value 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Label 2: Value 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Label 3: Value 3"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="   Details   "
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the border.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#cdcdcd" />
</shape>
```